# How to avoid duplicate codes that is common for all methods of a class?

Tags: java, dao, duplicates

In our application, in DAO layer every method follows almost same sequence:

```
public List getSomeValue(String[] parameters) {
    try {
        //Get connection from pool
        //Execute procedure
        //Process resultset
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //Error handling mechanism
    } finally {
        //Release connection
    }

    return someResult;  
}
```

All the commented lines in the above code describes the operation we are doing.

Now, other than process result-set part, everything is almost exactly same.

My question is, can we implement some kind of design, so that we don't have to write the same code again and again in each and every method? So that, we just have to write result-set processing part.

Utility methods are already in place. But again we have to call them in each and every procedure in exactly same sequence. Can we have something so that these predefined methods will be called automatically and we have to write only the part that differs? I'm not even sure if this is at all possible or not.

**Note:** We can not use any ORM tool like Hibernate.

Comment: re-usable methods, or inherited methods of a superclass come to mind

Comment: Why not just moving the repeating code to methods (in abstract parent class maybe) like: `Connection getConnectionFromPool()` and `void executeProcedure()`?

Comment: These methods are already in place. But again we have to call them in each and every procedure in exactly same sequence. Can we have something so that these predefined methods will be called automatically and we have to write only the part that differs? I'm not even sure if this is at all possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass in a `mapper` that knows how to convert the `ResultSet` into the List of elements you expect.  For example:

```
public List<T> getSomeValue(String[] parameters, ResultSetMapper<T> mapper) {
    try {
        //Get connection from pool
        //Execute procedure
        //Process resultset
        return mapper.convert(resultSet);  
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //Error handling mechanism
    } finally {
        //Release connection
    }
}

interface RowMapper<T> {
    List<T> convert(ResultSet resultSet);
}
```

You'd pass in different `mapper` implementations, and the `getSomeValue` method would stay the same, so you'd only need 1 implementation of it.

If you are using Spring in your project, you can use its `ResultSetExtractor` or `RowMapper` classes to do something similar.

Comment: If we have two methods getSomeValue1(), getSomeValue2(), don't we have to duplicate stuff?

Comment: You said that that those methods do exactly the same thing, except transform the ResultSet.  If this is true, you only need 1 implementation of `getSomeValue` and pass in different mappers.

Answer (score 1):

Since java 8 you method could be refactored to something like;

```
Object doSomething(){
    return doInTransaction(trans -> {
        return trans.load();
    });
}
```

Where `InTrans` is

```
public interface InTrans<T> {
    T call(Transaction transaction);
}
```

and `doInTransaction`

```
<T> T doInTransaction(InTrans<T> callable){
    try {
        Connection connection = ...
        return callable.call(connection));
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //Error handling mechanism
    } finally {
        //Release connection
    }

}
```

Alternatively you can use declarative transaction from `Spring`

Comment: I'll have a look into it and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This uses the same principle proposed by `talex` in his answer, except that for what you are looking for, I believe that what you want is to use the [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) functional interface (or some other similar interface) using a `ResultSet` as input.

So basically, all your fetching of the connection, procedure execution, looping of the resultset and the exception handling remains inside the one method without repetition.  And when you invoke the method, you pass in the code that will process each row.

It will look something like this:

```
public void callingCode() {
    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    performQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM ...",
            new String[]{"param1", "param2"},
            rs -> {
                try {
                    // process your row here.
                    someList.add(rs.getString("somecolumn"));
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
}

public void performQuery(String query, String[] parameters, Consumer<ResultSet> processRow) {
    try {
        //Get connection from pool
        //Execute procedure
        ResultSet rs = null; // pretend this comes from the procedure call.
        //Process resultset
        while (rs.next()) {
            processRow.accept(rs);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Error handling mechanism
    } finally {
        //Release resources
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The annoying thing with the `Consumer<T>` functional interface is that the method signature doesn't allow for any checked exceptions, so the `SQLException`s need to be handled explicitly (in the code above, you can see that I'm forced to wrap the `SQLException` in a `RuntimeException`).  To avoid this annoyance, you could choose not to use the built-in `Consumer<T>` functional interface, and instead, create your own that does include `throws SQLException` as part of the method signature.

`ResultSetConsumer` interface:

```
public interface ResultSetConsumer {
    void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

Adjusted code:

```
public void callingCode() {
    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    performQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM ...",
            new String[]{"param1", "param2"},
            rs -> {
                // process your row here.
                someList.add(rs.getString("somecolumn"));
            });
}

public void performQuery(String query, String[] parameters, ResultSetConsumer rsConsumer) {
    try {
        //Get connection from pool
        //Execute procedure
        ResultSet rs = null; // pretend this comes from the procedure call.
        //Process resultset
        while (rs.next()) {
            rsConsumer.processRow(rs);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Error handling mechanism
    } finally {
        //Release resources
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class having the common methods written there and then inherit the class from base class, so every child class will inherit them.

If having a super class is not an option (restricted by the framework or some other reasons), you can write a utility class having static methods for common functionality.